# Area of shape without all dimensions

Tags: geometry

[image]

Given the triangle pictured, I'm trying to figure out the area shaded in green. I'm completely stuck. Can you point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: You have probably heard about similar triangles.  Think about the picture some more.  It's problematic that the vertical segment of 3cm is not explicitly indicated to be perpendicular to the segment of 4cm, but that's my interpretation of the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: they are similar triangles by angle-angle similarity. (the small triangle that is in the big triangle).

Comment: Hmm.. ok so the ratio of the length/height for the small triangle should equal the ratio of l/h for big triangle. Thus 4/3 = 7/x, where x is height of big triangle. x = 5.25. Then area of green space is (2.25x3)/2 + 3x3 = 12.375 cm^2. Thanks!